# How to exclude/eliminate invalid areas (such as NoData, cloud, water, etc) from raster so that it does not effect the accuracy assessment?

Tags: python, raster, accuracy, nodata, confusion-matrix

I have two classified raster (snow cover % 10-100) one is prepared from coarse resolution and another is from finer resolution. I am doing accuracy assessment and matrix calculation of snow cover %. However, both classified raster has invalid classes like NoData (-9999), cloud (value=205), water (210), permanent ice(215).

Now both the raster has same pixel size after resampling and covering same area by using `gdalwarp`

These classes/values are **effecting the accuracy assessment**. I only want to comapre both raster in terms of snow cover %. **How can I eliminate those value from both raster??**

My code

```
#reading in array Snow cover % raster from true raster (finer resolution)
img= rasterio.open(filepath+'20020310_ndsi_reclass.tif')
img_r=img.read(1)

#Reading in array Snow cover % from prediction raster (coarser resolution)
img_pre= rasterio.open(filepath+ '20020310_ndsi_reclass_pred.tif')
img_pre_r=img_pre.read(1)

#making it 1dimesional
y_true= np.ravel(img_r)
y_pred= np.ravel(img_pre_r)
y_true = y_true.astype('int')
y_pred = y_pred.astype('int')

from sklearn import metrics
print(metrics.classification_report(y_true, y_pred))
```

[image: the classification report]

Matrix calculation

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

cm=confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)


import seaborn as sn
ax= plt.subplot()
sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, ax = ax); #annot=True to annotate cells

# labels, title and ticks
ax.set_xlabel('Predicted labels');ax.set_ylabel('True labels'); 
ax.set_title('Confusion Matrix'); 
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(['nodata','0','10', '20', '30', '40', '50', '60', '70', '80', '90', '100', 'cloud', 'water', 'ice']); ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels(['nodata','0','10', '20', '30', '40', '50', '60', '70', '80', '90', '100', 'cloud', 'water', 'ice']);
```

[image: plotting matrix]
**How to exclude  Nodata, cloud, water, and ice from both the report?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and maybe do something like:

```py
y_true= np.ravel(img_r)
y_pred= np.ravel(img_pre_r)
y_true = y_true.astype('int')
y_pred = y_pred.astype('int')

indx = np.where((y_true != -9999) & (y_true != 205) & (y_true != 210) & (y_true != 215))

y_true = y_true[indx]
y_pred = y_pred[indx]
```

Or apply the `np.where` call to both true and pred arrays and use [logical operators](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.logic.html#logical-operations).

Comment: Thanks @Ryan it worked for me in this case where I converted 2D to 1D array. How can I make it work for normal raster 2d array? As I am doing `zonal_stats` from `rasterstats` [https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/CSC18/lessons/L6/zonal-statistics.html] . Those invalid class is dominating the zonal statistic. I tried `indx = np.where((y_true != -9999) & (y_true != 205) & (y_true != 210) & (y_true != 215))

y_true = y_true[indx]` but it is making the array 1D however I need 2d array for this application.

Comment: @Tua Check out the [nan stats](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/routines.statistics.html#averages-and-variances) in numpy: nanmean, nanmedian, etc.. You can supply one or more of those functions to rasterstats as an [add_stats](https://pythonhosted.org/rasterstats/manual.html#user-defined-statistics) argument.

Comment: there is no problem running in `rasterstats` however it is taking all those unwanted areas like (205, 210) and giving results accordingly. **I meant to ask you that how can remove those unwanted value (like 205,210, etc) from 2D array** the `indx` above is for 1D array how can I apply for this eliminating those unwanted values from 2D array? I have tried putting `:` but did not work

Comment: @Tua you pass a 2D array to `np.where` like this: `indx = np.where((img_r == 210.0) | (img_r == 205.0 ))`. And then index and reassign the array values directly: `img_r[indx] = np.nan`. And then pass it to rasterstats to with the nan functions.

Comment: Thank you so much for looking into it  it worked :)